# Modificar la posición de un JInternalFrame

Tags: java, eclipse

Quisiera saber como modificar la posicion de un JInterframe que está dentro de un JdesktopPane, el JInterframe quisiera que aparezca en la esquina superior izquiera como se muestra en la imagen.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa:

```
// x, y, w, h
JInternalFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

[Documentación del método setBounds - docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds-java.awt.Rectangle-)